# Show/Hide prices in Woocommerce by using $_SESSION

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

I want a logged in user (they don't have access to the admin panel) to have the opportunity to hide/show prices in my webshop by clicking a link in the footer. I'm using Woocommerce and might be making things too complicated for myself in my solution, it was a long time ago I worked with sessions so I am very rusty.. I managed to hide prices but I can't figure out how to make them show again, especially in a way that doesn't feel like cheating. Note that I already have checked whether the user is logged in or not.

**Code updated**
**I start a session with my functions.php, like this:**

```
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}

add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');
```

**The form that helps me set the `$_SESSION`:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="process_form">
    <?php if($_SESSION['session_price'] == true) { ?>
    <input type="submit" name="sessiondestroy" id="sessionDestroy" onclick="showPricesAgain()" value="Dölj priser"></input>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="inputsession" value="true">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**The code in functions.php the suppose to handle the form**

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_process_form', 'process_form_data' );
add_action( 'admin_post_process_form', 'process_form_data' );
function process_form_data() {
    $_SESSION['session_price'] = $_POST['inputsession'];
if($_SESSION["session_price"] == true) { 


    //Remove single product price
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
    //add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','print_login_to_see', 30 );

    //Remove loop price
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);

    //Remove loop add to cart
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart'); ?>

    <style>
        .product_list_widget .woocommerce-Price-amount {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .price>.amount {
            display: none !important;
        }

    </style>
   <?php }  
}
```

Do I go for a `if/else`-statement in the `form` as above? Now I call for a function that destroys the session if the session is true, I dont know if thats the best approach...

Maybe too many questions now, but setting the `<?php $_SESSION['session_price'] = $_POST['inputsession']; ?>`
just below the form feels wrong. Can I somehow do that in **functions.php**
or should I do that in **header.php** ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write this in functions.php.

Use admin-post.php for handle forms like [here](http://www.adaptiveweb.com.au/handle-post-and-get-requests-in-wordpress-using-admin-post-php/)

Comment: OKay great, so at least I got that right.. So I set the `$_SESSION` in admin-post.php, I think I can make that work too. But then I'm stuck.

Comment: Whats wrong? Handle your form in functions.php by admin-post.php and set $_SESSION variable to true or false. Than on hook `woocommerce_init` create action with your removing actions.

`add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'remove_prices' );
function remove_prices() {
 if ( isset( $_SESSION['session_price'] ) && true === $_SESSION['session_price'] ) {
  // remove actions and add additional styles
 }
}`

Comment: Now I'm even more lost... I updated my code above to what I have now after reading the link you posted.

Comment: Al right. Using admin-post.php you handle your form and set $_SESSION variable. Then when woocommerce initialize - you check your session and if it true, hide your prices.

Comment: I wrote hook with action. Replace my comment `// remove actions and add additional styles` to your remove_actions from question body. And place this hook in functions.php file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164603/discussion-between-teninchhero-and-maxim-sarandi).

Comment: It wont even call the `function process_form_data()`

Comment: Lets go in chat